# Result of comparing hardcoded strings with ==

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The following C code attempts to compare hardcoded strings using `==`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool test_address_aliasing() {
    const char * a = "1";
    const char * b = "1";
    return a==b;
}
```

This will compare pointers to `a` and `b`, and an optimizing compiler will most likely combine the references to `a` and `b` to store them in the same place, thus resulting in `a==b` being true. However, a compiler is not required to combine references to equivalent strings, so is the actual result implementation defined? (I am most interested in C99 if the answer depends on the version of the C spec.)

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.4.5 String literals 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined.* C99 draft standard n1256: *6.4.5 String literals 6 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: The rules for this sort of comparison are essentially independent of the version of C.  For comparing strings with unequal content, the result is guaranteed to be unequal; if the content is equal, it is unspecified whether they reference the same locations or not, so the result could be equal or unequal — both are acceptable, and reliable code cannot rely on either result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unspecified whether or not two string constants with the same content point to the same object.  Section 6.4.5p7 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding string constants states:

> It  is  unspecified  whether  these  arrays  are  distinct  provided 
>   their  elements  have  the appropriate  values.   If  the  program 
>   attempts  to  modify  such  an  array,  the  behavior  is undefined.

The actual pointer comparison is valid in either case (see [C11 6.5.9p6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers,
>   both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to
>   one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a
>   pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a
>   pointer to the start of a different array  object  that  happens  to 
>   immediately  follow  the  first  array  object  in  the  address
>   space.

Comment: It won't be implementation defined, it would be unspecified.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, just found the relevant passage.  Updated.

Comment: I'd say the comparison is unspecified if the contents of the two literals is the same. If the contents differ, the comparison must return a false value. So you cannot get a false positive from the comparison, a fact which might be useful.

Comment: @rici `"p" == "p\0q"` may return true I think

Comment: @L.F.: `strcmp` would return equality in that case. So true would be correct, if it happened.

Answer (score 2):

From C standard, 6.4.5 "String literals", item 6:

> It is unspecified whether these [string literals] arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values.

That means, result of this comparison is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question specifically sought advice on C99 (not C17), relevant quotes from the 1999 C standard follow;

Section 6.4.5 "String Literals", para 6 says

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Section 6.5.2.5 "Compound literals", para 8.

> String literals, and compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate
>   distinct objects.

The above also refers to footnote 82, which (while informative, not normative) says;

> This allows implementations to share storage for string literals and constant compound literals with the same or overlapping representations.

Para 14 of the same section also provides an example;

> EXAMPLE 6 Like string literals, const-qualified compound literals can be placed into read-only memory and can even be shared. For example,
>
> ```
>      (const char []){"abc"} == "abc"
> ```
>
> might yield 1 if the literals’ storage is shared.

Section J.1 (informative) lists a bunch of things that are unspecified in the standard, of which the 14th in the list is

> Whether two string literals result in distinct arrays (6.4.5).

From all of the above, it is unspecified whether two string literals with equivalent content are distinct.  Two string literals of the form `"abc"` are allowed but not required to be at the same address in memory.   This also means that the result of a (pointer) comparison would be unspecified.

Answer (score -1):

if you do so:

`char *a = "1";
char *b ="1";`

and then:

`if(a==b){ DO SOMETHING}` HERE you are comparing the address of memory, where the two pointers are stored.

To compare the content of the memory where the variables are stored(and so to compare the value of the 2 variables) you have to do so:

`if(*a == *b){DO SOMETHING}`

I hope you mean that